# Protocol handshake not identified in firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Can anybody please help me resolve this error? It is not indicated clearly. Is it a problem with versions?

**Error**

```
error: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Comment: What's the programming angle to this question?

Comment: code used: java.util.Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
       java.util.Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
          subWindowHandler = (String) iterator.next(); }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); 
         
        System.out.println("@Given: I am a single applicant1");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("button accept")).click();
        System.out.println("@Given: I am a single applicant2");
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);

Comment: You have to supply, version of selenium, version of geckodriver, version of firefox that you are using.  Btw, if they are not the latest then update to the latest and try again.

Comment: firefox: 53.0.2(32 bit)
selenium - 3.4.0
gecko-0.16.1- win32  i think its all the latest version, but still the error exists

Comment: in addition my system is   64bit operating system

Comment: and windows10pro